# Left shape inside a card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to do this card. But I don't know how to the green shape part. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a row create a container and give it DecorationBox and some radius to upper and bottom left corners and a second child as text. You can modify the following example code according to your needs.

```
 Container(
          child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5))),
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text('data'),
        ],
      )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how I want it.

```
class NotificationBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  final Radius radius = Radius.circular(10.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 8,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: radius,
                bottomLeft: radius,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kLightBlack,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: radius,
                    bottomRight: radius,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Some pretty message',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```